# Data format conversion to be combined with string split in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have following data frame `oridf`:

```
test_name   gp1_0month  gp2_0month  gp1_1month  gp2_1month  gp1_3month  gp2_3month
Test_1  136 137 152 143 156 150
Test_2  130 129 81  78  86  80
Test_3  129 128 68  68  74  71
Test_4  40  40  45  43  47  46
Test_5  203 201 141 134 149 142
Test_6  170 166 134 116 139 125

oridf <- structure(list(test_name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Test_1", 
"Test_2", "Test_3", "Test_4", "Test_5", "Test_6"), class = "factor"), 
    gp1_0month = c(136L, 130L, 129L, 40L, 203L, 170L), gp2_0month = c(137L, 
    129L, 128L, 40L, 201L, 166L), gp1_1month = c(152L, 81L, 68L, 
    45L, 141L, 134L), gp2_1month = c(143L, 78L, 68L, 43L, 134L, 
    116L), gp1_3month = c(156L, 86L, 74L, 47L, 149L, 139L), gp2_3month = c(150L, 
    80L, 71L, 46L, 142L, 125L)), .Names = c("test_name", "gp1_0month", 
"gp2_0month", "gp1_1month", "gp2_1month", "gp1_3month", "gp2_3month"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I need to convert it to following format:

```
test_name   month   group   value
Test_1      0       gp1     136
Test_1      0       gp2     137
Test_1      1       gp1     152
Test_1      1       gp2     143
.....
```

Hence, conversion would involve splitting of `gp1` and `0month`, etc. from columns 2:7 of the original data frame `oridf` so that I can plot it with following command:

```
qplot(data=newdf, x=month, y=value, geom=c("point","line"), color=test_name, linetype=group)
```

How can I convert these data? I tried the `melt` command, but I cannot combine it with the `strsplit` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would use melt like you had done.

```
library(reshape2)
mm <- melt(oridf)
```

then there is also a `colsplit` function you can use in the `reshape2` library as well. Here we use it on the variable column to split at the underscore and the "m" in month (ignoring the rest)

```
info <- colsplit(mm$variable, "(_|m)", c("group","month", "xx"))[,-3]
```

Then we can recombine the data

```
newdf <- cbind(mm[,1, drop=F], info, mm[,3, drop=F])

# head(newdf)
#   test_name group month value
# 1    Test_1   gp1     0   136
# 2    Test_2   gp1     0   130
# 3    Test_3   gp1     0   129
# 4    Test_4   gp1     0    40
# 5    Test_5   gp1     0   203
# 6    Test_6   gp1     0   170
```

And we can plot it using the `qplot` command you supplied above

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `gather` from the tidyr package to convert from wide to long and then use`separate` from the same package to separate the `group_month` column into `group` and `month` columns.  Finally using `mutate` from dplyr smf `extract_numeric` from tidyr extract the numeric part of `month`.

```
library(dplyr)
# devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(tidyr)

newdf <- oridf %>%
   gather(group_month, value, -test_name) %>% 
   separate(group_month, into = c("group", "month")) %>% 
   mutate(month = extract_numeric(month))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am unable to connect to r-cran repository to install dplyr and tidyr. I will test this ASAP.

Comment: @rnso As far as I know, `tidyr` is not on CRAN yet, you can install it with the `devtools` package: `install_github("hadley/tidyr")`